# Integer.parseInt() doesn't parse large negative numbers

Tags: java

Why is NumberFormatException is thrown when i try `Integer.parseInt("80000010", 16)`?? That **IS** a 32-bit number, which is the size of java's int.

EDIT: 
The best part is this...

```
int z = 0x80000010;
System.err.println("equal to " + z);
```

Prints `-2147483632` which is indeed `0x80000010` according to my calculator ;)

Comment: 80000010 isn't a negative number in my universe.

Comment: You say in the title 'negative numbers' but the example is of a positive number.

Comment: it's something 'evil' that Java does not support unsigned int

Comment: A lack of unsigned is easy to work around. But I agree you shouldn't have to. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
int value = (int) Long.parseLong("80000010", 16)
```

**Update:**

With [Java 8 update](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/jdk_8_is_released) (2014) you can write

```
int value = Integer.parseUnsignedInt("80000010", 16);
```

Answer (score 10):

Because parseInt "parses the string argument as a signed integer", as specified in the API documentation. The value 80000010 with radix 16 is outside the valid range for a signed 32 byte value.

Answer (score 4):

80,00,00,10<sub>16</sub> = 2,147,483,664<sub>10</sub>

Whilst a Java integer has a range of -2,147,483,648<sub>10</sub> to 2,147,483,647<sub>10</sub>.

Answer (score 2):

For those stuck with Java <= 7, [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html#parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String)) provides a utility for parsing ints as
unsigned:

```
UnsignedInts.parseUnsignedInt("ffffffff", 16);
> -1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the first parameter is signed integer, so for negative numbers you have to give minus sign explicitly. And in your case you have big **unsgined** number outside the integer range.

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing it with base 16. So it is greater than the maximum for integer.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt() takes in a signed integer as it's input. This means the input has to be between `"7FFFFFFF"` and `"-80000000"`. Note the negative sign before `0x80000000`. The input you want for `-2147483632` is the positive `2147483632 (0x7FFFFFF0)` with a negative sign in front, so `Integer.parseInt("-7FFFFFF0", 16)`.