# error while converting hexadecimal to latitude and longitude in java

Tags: java, latitude-longitude, numberformatexception

```
 public String getLatitude(String hex) {
        int latStart=0;
        String str09 = hex.substring(latStart,latStart+8);
        System.out.println("latitude Hex::"+str09);
        Integer outDec = Integer.parseInt(str09, 16);
        double d = outDec / new Double(1000);
        System.out.println("Hex to float>>>" + d);
        double lat = d /`enter code here` 3600;
        return String.valueOf(lat);
    }

public String getLongitude(String hex) throws Exception {
    int lonStart=8;
    String str09 = hex.substring(lonStart,lonStart+8);
    System.out.println("Longitude Hex::"+str09);
    Integer outDec = Integer.parseInt(str09,16);
    double d = outDec / new Double(1000);
    System.out.println("Hex to float>>>" + asHex);
    double lon = d / 3600;
    return String.valueOf(lon);
}
```

hexstring -->090bc3b3ed1b479c

I am trying to convert this to latitude and longitude. Actual output is 
latitude Hex::090bc3b3
latitude:::42.157205277777784

Longitude Hex::ed1b479c
longitude:::-88.04980555555555

I am getting NumberFormatException when i am trying to convert into Interger values. Here is the code i am working on:

I am getting exception i am converting longitude hex string into Interger.

```
public String getLongitude(String hex) throws Exception {
    int lonStart=8;
    String str09 = hex.substring(lonStart,lonStart+8);
    System.out.println("latitude Hex::"+str09);
    System.out.println("Longitude Hex::"+str09);
    Long outDec = Long.parseLong(str09, 16);
    double d = outDec / new Double(1000);
    System.out.println("Hex to float>>>" + d);
    double lon = d / 3600;
    return String.valueOf(lon);
}
```

i also tried with Long but here is is what i am getting :longitude:::1104.9966655555554

Comment: Why is your argument named `base64` in the second `getLongiture` method? Are you using base64 encoding?

Comment: I am getting input as base 64 string which is converted into hex string .. I have compared the hex string before encoding and after decoding the base64 which looks good. But the issue is while converting the hex string into Signed decimal values. I have changed the variable name to hex now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with parsing negative values. Using the `090bc3b3ed1b479c` string as input, you probably got `NumberFormatException: For input string: "ed1b479c"` because that number is too big to be stored in `int`.

Java 8 added `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` which will solve your problem, output after changing to unsigned conversion:

```
latitude Hex::090bc3b3
Hex to float>>>151765.939
Lat: 42.157205277777784

Longitude Hex::ed1b479c
Hex to float>>>-316979.3
Lon: -88.04980555555555
```

Note that `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` will still return a *signed* `int`, but it will treat the input string as unsigned.

**Edit:**

For pre-Java 8, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488885/integer-parseint-doesnt-parse-large-negative-numbers) question:

```
int value = (int) Long.parseLong(yourSringHere, 16);
```

Comment: is there a solution in java 7..i am currently using java 7